# Can we use softmax activation when all value of an array is zero?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, softmax

I have a `5 x 5 x 21` array. The last dimension represents channels.  In a few channels, only one of the pixel values is `1` and the rest of the values are `0`. For other channels, all of the pixel values are `0`. I am applying `softmax` activation along the spatial dimension while training a deep neural network. Is it a good idea to use `softmax` even when all the values is zero, i.e. sum of all pixel values along the spatial dimension is not equal to `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if understand your question.
Softmax should be applied in places where we want [almost] one-hot distribution in trained network. Output of softmax defines distribution (sum is equal to 1) but there are no restrictions about input of softmax. If you pass all 0 to softmax you will get uniform distribution as an output.

Whether it make sense it depends on the goal of the network